# Time series with 4 lectures in each year

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I would like to make a `time series`. But I do not understand how to put adequate `frequency()`in my data. Because I have 4 lectures in each year.

I am running this code with different `frequency()`.

```
col <- ts(data, start=(2005), end=(2017), frecuency=3)

col2 <- ts(data, start=(2005), end=(2017), frecuency=4)
```

This error appears in both frequencies:

> Error in ts(data, start = (2005), end = (2017), frecuency = 3) :
> unused argument (frecuency = 3)

Short example of data:

```
data<-dput(data2[1:50,c(1,5)])
structure(list(`Año(aaaa) Trimestre` = c("2005-I", "2005-II", 
"2005-III", "2005-IV", "2006-I", "2006-II", "2006-III", "2006-IV", 
"2007-I", "2007-II", "2007-III", "2007-IV", "2008-I", "2008-II", 
"2008-III", "2008-IV", "2009-I", "2009-II", "2009-III", "2009-IV", 
"2010-I", "2010-II", "2010-III", "2010-IV", "2011-I", "2011-II", 
"2011-III", "2011-IV", "2012-I", "2012-II", "2012-III", "2012-IV", 
"2013-I", "2013-II", "2013-III", "2013-IV", "2014-I", "2014-II", 
"2014-III", "2014-IV", "2015-I", "2015-II", "2015-III", "2015-IV", 
"2016-I", "2016-II", "2016-III", "2016-IV", "2017-I", "2017-II"
), Intereses = c(3487.7340796913, 2636.1720431842, 4098.7810605988, 
1127.7775577085, 3898.7200068568, 3173.4231650307, 5200.9872227416, 
2568.5529693648, 4563.7053724986, 3689.8479045882, 5328.9957833292, 
3027.943784559, 3216.4330560052, 3590.2597494772, 4921.7015570933, 
3509.2270647808, 3267.2335649236, 3752.591130593, 5309.6809854114, 
3640.7569827354, 2808.0944016763, 4384.7273283165, 5153.7080387692, 
3293.4313083865, 2888.6304625115, 5441.9009141676, 5345.4405829456, 
4035.0252381896, 3274.6679703078, 4440.9410689445, 5620.2510678808, 
3971.8280391794, 3137.8612868065, 4763.6464493441, 5098.6004975375, 
4370.5127517673, 2916.9675160472, 4461.8158321922, 6220.9851841919, 
3750.8295027979, 3173.8139113252, 4124.7981239368, 7800.2754718405, 
5112.4716690847, 4093.9792156983, 5224.9834134052, 10451.3900750738, 
3725.9879281201, 4051.180479499, 7013.2845555995)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Is it simply that you spelled `frequency` incorrectly? It's with a `q` not a `c`.

Comment: I count myself very fortunate that the vast majority of function arguments in R are generalized fashioned after my primary spoken language (the exception being, of course, `ggplot2` and its preference towards `colour` ;-).

Comment: Thanks @neilfws, I dont see this error. Because this word is a *false cognate* with my mother tongue (Spanish). Because in Spanhis we said `frecuencia` but in English is `frequency`.
Well check!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can define your data2 as

```
data2 <- structure(list(`Año(aaaa) Trimestre` = c("2005-I", "2005-II", 
                                                  "2005-III", "2005-IV", "2006-I", "2006-II", "2006-III", "2006-IV", 
                                                  "2007-I", "2007-II", "2007-III", "2007-IV", "2008-I", "2008-II", 
                                                  "2008-III", "2008-IV", "2009-I", "2009-II", "2009-III", "2009-IV", 
                                                  "2010-I", "2010-II", "2010-III", "2010-IV", "2011-I", "2011-II", 
                                                  "2011-III", "2011-IV", "2012-I", "2012-II", "2012-III", "2012-IV", 
                                                  "2013-I", "2013-II", "2013-III", "2013-IV", "2014-I", "2014-II", 
                                                  "2014-III", "2014-IV", "2015-I", "2015-II", "2015-III", "2015-IV", 
                                                  "2016-I", "2016-II", "2016-III", "2016-IV", "2017-I", "2017-II"
), Intereses = c(3487.7340796913, 2636.1720431842, 4098.7810605988, 
                 1127.7775577085, 3898.7200068568, 3173.4231650307, 5200.9872227416, 
                 2568.5529693648, 4563.7053724986, 3689.8479045882, 5328.9957833292, 
                 3027.943784559, 3216.4330560052, 3590.2597494772, 4921.7015570933, 
                 3509.2270647808, 3267.2335649236, 3752.591130593, 5309.6809854114, 
                 3640.7569827354, 2808.0944016763, 4384.7273283165, 5153.7080387692, 
                 3293.4313083865, 2888.6304625115, 5441.9009141676, 5345.4405829456, 
                 4035.0252381896, 3274.6679703078, 4440.9410689445, 5620.2510678808, 
                 3971.8280391794, 3137.8612868065, 4763.6464493441, 5098.6004975375, 
                 4370.5127517673, 2916.9675160472, 4461.8158321922, 6220.9851841919, 
                 3750.8295027979, 3173.8139113252, 4124.7981239368, 7800.2754718405, 
                 5112.4716690847, 4093.9792156983, 5224.9834134052, 10451.3900750738, 
                 3725.9879281201, 4051.180479499, 7013.2845555995)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                   -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Then convert to timeseries (spelling "frequency" as noted in comments) as

```
col <- ts(data2$`Año(aaaa) Trimestre`, start=(2005), end=(2017), frequency=3)
```

which gives

```
col
Time Series:
Start = c(2005, 1) 
End = c(2017, 1) 
Frequency = 3 
 [1]   2005-I  2005-II 2005-III  2005-IV   2006-I  2006-II 2006-III
 [8]  2006-IV   2007-I  2007-II 2007-III  2007-IV   2008-I  2008-II
[15] 2008-III  2008-IV   2009-I  2009-II 2009-III  2009-IV   2010-I
[22]  2010-II 2010-III  2010-IV   2011-I  2011-II 2011-III  2011-IV
[29]   2012-I  2012-II 2012-III  2012-IV   2013-I  2013-II 2013-III
[36]  2013-IV   2014-I
```

Comment: Many thanks @Brian Syzdek. Was an error for use a *false cognate*. Im going to run this.